# Does firebase hosting gzip my assets automatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I ask this because the response header of my fetched assets contains no

> Content-Encoding:gzip

Comment: I just quickly tested and my responses definitely have a gzip header. For example on a css file, I get `content-encoding:gzip`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318491/serving-gzipped-files-on-firebase-hosting/34701286#34701286

Comment: this is the response for my css file:                                                                                 ```Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3360
Content-Type:text/css; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:37:34 GMT
ETag:"83bab03bd7b4d7f01f03858b2c1e58a2"
Last-Modified:Wed, 14 Sep 2016 11:19:16 GMT
Server:nginx
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:1
X-Powered-By:Express
X-Served-By:cache-sjc3640-SJC```

Comment: Frank, is there something required of me to do so it will g-zip?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything specific for the site I tested on.

Comment: Can you share the URL that's having the problem? The gzipping is automatic for text files and happens as long as Accept-Encoding allows for compression.

Comment: Michael, I sent you an email with the app url.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Check https://ccs-dev-firebase.firebaseapp.com/  it also is not gziped the request header does have accept-encoding: gzip,  but the response is not gziped.